# Why is my Apache Virtual Hosts configuration not working correctly?

Tags: apache, virtualhost

## Background

I have been using an Apache server with only one site and this has been working really well. Recently, I have had to create two more sites locally, and I found [this](https://www.git-tower.com/blog/apache-on-macos/) guide that showed how to do this. I also referred to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12339044/how-to-run-multiple-sites-on-one-apache-instance) stack overflow question which also helped me a lot.

My problem is that when I visit the three hosts I made in `/etc/hosts` and configured in `httpd-vhosts.conf`, it is not working and says `its-site.test refused to connect.` when I try to visit it in browser.

I attempted to resolve the issue by referring to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31504003/apache-virtual-hosts-not-working-as-expected) stack overflow question which helped me to understand the configuration much better, but it is still not working and results in the same issue.

Needless to say I am very new to Apache so I might be overlooking something obvious.

## My intended setup

I have three different sites which I want to use named virtual hosts to access in browser during my development process. Rather than using one local host and a few named domains, I wanted each of them to be named domains:

- its-site.test
- its-cab.test
- its-gallery.test

## Hosts file

`/etc/hosts`

```
##
# Host Database
#
# localhost is used to configure the loopback interface
# when the system is booting.  Do not change this entry.
##
127.0.0.1       localhost
255.255.255.255 broadcasthost
::1             localhost

127.0.0.1       its-site.test
127.0.0.1       its-cab.test
127.0.0.1       its-gallery.test
```

## httpd configuration

`/opt/homebrew/etc/httpd/httpd.conf`

```
Listen 80

Include /opt/homebrew/etc/httpd/extra/httpd-vhosts.conf
LoadModule rewrite_module lib/httpd/modules/mod_rewrite.so
ServerName localhost:80

# Also enabled PHP but not including the config here as it may not be relevant
```

## vhosts configuration

`/opt/homebrew/etc/httpd/extra/httpd-vhosts.conf`

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName its-site.test
    ServerAlias *.its-site.test
    DocumentRoot "/Users/ciesinsg/Documents/Repositories/its-site/web"

    <directory "/Users/ciesinsg/Documents/Repositories/its-site/web">
        Require all granted
        AllowOverride All
    </directory>
</VirtualHost>


<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName its-cab.test
    ServerAlias *.its-cab.test
    DocumentRoot "/Users/ciesinsg/Documents/Repositories/its-cab/web"

    <directory "/Users/ciesinsg/Documents/Repositories/its-cab/web">
        Require all granted
        AllowOverride All
    </directory>
</VirtualHost>


<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName its-gallery.test
    ServerAlias *.its-gallery.test
    DocumentRoot "/Users/ciesinsg/Documents/Repositories/its-gallery/web"

    <directory "/Users/ciesinsg/Documents/Repositories/its-gallery/web">
        Require all granted
        AllowOverride All
    </directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

## Question

Does anybody see where I made a mistake with this configuration and can point me towards the solution?

## Additional Information

- M1 Macbook Air
- Apache and PHP installed using homebrew
- ~~Points to my drupal site/web folders~~

## Previous Single Site working Config

As stated earlier, I had this working well when I was serving only one site. My only configuration was with `httpd.conf` and did not configure `/etc/hosts` or `httpd-vhosts.conf`. My working `httpd.conf` file looked like:

```
Listen 80
DocumentRoot "/Users/ciesinsg/Documents/Repositories/its-gallery/web"
<Directory "/Users/ciesinsg/Documents/Repositories/its-gallery/web">

# Also enabled PHP
```

I removed the `DocumentRoot` and `<Directory>` when I configured VirtualHosts.

Comment: This is a networking/server configuration issue. PHP/drupal aren't related.

Comment: If you comment out the last 2 `<VirtualHost *:80>` and restart apache this is working as intended?

Comment: I'll edit the Drupal out. I left it in in case it may shed some light on my issue. 

I commented out the last 2 `VirtualHost *:80> blocks and restarted apache, but it has the same issue and says the site wont load. I am attempting to reach its-site.test as per my hosts file.

Comment: So it as you had it previously, with just the 1 host?

Comment: No, previously I did not have a VirtualHost or hosts configuration, and I only had an httpd configuration with `Listen 80`, and `DocumentRoot` and `<Directory>` were pointing at my `site/web` folder. This served my single website without issues.

Comment: This would probably be better on https://serverfault.com/ in that case. I thought it was an issue with the changes but this is a whole new configuration you have. I've always had the configuration files in `conf.d`. Maybe that changed with apache version you are running.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to resolve the problem using the below solution:

## Test PHP

First, I tested my configurations in `etc/hosts` using ping:

```
ciesinsg@NB-00304-H14872 ~ % ping its-site.test
PING its-site.test (127.0.0.1): 56 data bytes
64 bytes from 127.0.0.1: icmp_seq=0 ttl=64 time=0.051 ms
```

This confirmed that the site was routing to the right IP matching my config.

## Check Virtual Hosts

This was done manually by referring to [these](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/vhosts/examples.html) docs and double checking the [guide](https://www.git-tower.com/blog/apache-on-macos/) I followed. I am not aware of any tests to confirm the configuration is working correctly, but after reading a few guides and docs about virtual hosts, I was pretty confident that the configuration did not have any issues and the problem must be elsewhere.

## Check httpd.conf

This configurations is the longest out of the ones I listed by default. Consequently, this was a manual process. My solution involved opening `httpd-default.conf` which is an adjacent configuration file that appears to have the default configurations from the `httpd.conf` file. On the Homebrew installation of Apache, this is located in the `/opt/homebrew/etc/httpd/extra/` where the `httpd.conf` file is also located. I compared these two configurations side by side and removed my configurations from my earlier attempts.

In my case, I found that I had accidentally duplicated my PHP configuration in the `httpd.conf` file and in `httpd-php.conf` file. I removed all of my configurations and followed through the guide once again, ensuring that my `Include` and `LoadModule` statements were placed after the same statements.

After removing my configurations and configuring it more carefully, I tested the sites in the browser and they were all working as expected.